# Eigenvalues of graph's laplacians

Tags: spectral-graph-theory, graph-laplacian

I'm trying to tackle a question from a homework assignment and one of the problems concerns the relation between eigenvalues of a graph's laplacian and its complement's laplacian. The relation is:

$$λ_j (G') = n − λ_{n+2−j} (G)\;,$$

or more comfortably:

$$λ_j (G') + λ_{n+2−j} (G) = n\;,$$

where $G'$ is the graph's complement and $n$ is the number of vertices. Does anybody have any words of wisdom for me concerning this particular relation?

Asked differently, I would like to ask for advice concerning the relation between a laplacian of a graph to the laplacian of its complement.
I know, and can easily prove that the following relation holds:

$$L(G) + L(G') = nI - J\;,$$

where $J$ is the matrix of ones; however, I fail to use that to prove the earlier.

I would appreciate any guidance in the matter.
Thank you

Update: Let's say we take the equation: $L(G)+L(G')=nI-J$. First of all, I notice that $nI-J$ is also the laplacian of $K_n$ (meaning $G$ completed to all edges), therefore its eigenvalues are $0$ and $(n-1)$ eigenvalues of $n$ (I believe this is what you were saying before). If I multiply both sides by the matrix of $L(G)$'s eigenvectors, $L(G)$ goes to the eigenvalues matrix of $G$ and $L(G')$ goes to its eigenvalue matrix, only I notice said reversing occurs, which allows the relation which started the question. Could you possibly afford an explanation as to why the reversing occurs?

Comment: Please check whether my edit reflects what you wanted to express. You can find a tutorial and reference for formatting math on this site [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

The matrix $J$ has one eigenvalue $n$, with the corresponding eigenspace $E_n$ formed by the vectors with all entries equal, and $n-1$ eigenvalues $0$, with the corresponding eigenspace $E_0$ formed by all vectors that sum to $0$. A Laplacian matrix has eigenvalue $0$ for $E_n$, and since it's symmetric, its eigenspaces are orthogonal, so the remaining eigenspaces together form $E_0$. Knowing this, you can use the relation $L(G)+L(G')=nI-J$ to show that the eigenvectors of $L(G)$ are also eigenvectors of $L(G')$ and vice versa, and to express their eigenvalues in terms of each other. Since a Laplacian matrix is positive-semidefinite, the $0$ eigenvalue is the least eigenvalue, corresponding to $j=1$, and the order of the remaining eigenvalues is reversed; that explains the change in indexing from $j$ running from $2$ to $n$ to $n+2-j$ running from $n$ to $2$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I took into notice your comment: "Knowing this, you can use the relation L(G)+L(G′)=nI−J to show that the eigenvectors of L(G) are also eigenvectors of L(G′) and vice versa, and to express their eigenvalues in terms of each other." This is exactly what I am struggling to do. Any advice? Again, thank you

Comment: Can someone explain:  Knowing this, you can use the relation L(G)+L(G′)=nI−J to show that the eigenvectors of L(G) are also eigenvectors of L(G′) and vice versa, and to express their eigenvalues in terms of each other. Thank you!

Comment: This is the standard proof for this assertion, certainly right. Do you happen to know whether there is an alternative proof that only relies upon variational principles (=Rayleigh quotient)?